# Start / exec a process with initial stack at a custom address

Tags: c, linux, assembly, stack, callstack

I would like to change the starting stack address of a program on linux.

I've checked a bit the kernel source, found out about

```
extern void start_thread(struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long new_ip,
                           unsigned long new_sp);
```

from
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/29c395c77a9a514c5857c45ceae2665e9bd99ac7/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h

But I didn't find a way to inluence it from outside (of the kernel).

Ideally some configuration of my OS (debian) for a defined program would be perfect. But I don't know how to do that ...

I know about some stack related function like setrlimit() and ulimit() but that doesn't do the job.

May be gdb has some features like that? (It's not a problem if the program runs inside gdb.)

Since it's a program that I wrote, I also thought about doing a big malloc at program startup and change esp/ebp to point to it. But that's not ideal.

If anybody know some dark features of Linux process creation that would be nice!

Comment: Why do you want to change the stack pointer?

Comment: [`clone3(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) can apparently do this for a copy of the current process (like a generalized fork).  But it wouldn't survive across an execve unless clone can also set some kind of flag that affects execve.

Comment: I'm developping an x86 emulator. And In my emulator the stack pointer can't be very far from the code program (for perfomance issues). I want to know it the emulator is not wrong in the calculation, so I'm tracing a program exec in gdb and replay it in my emulator.

Comment: I'll look into clone() but I don't think it will help :/

Comment: After your program starts, if your stack isn't where you want it, you *could* clone3 your process with a specified location/size for the new stack (and exit the original process).  But it's probably better and certainly more efficient to just `mmap` a new stack and switch to it.  (And you don't have to get all the other clone flags right like CLONE_PARENT to not detach from the shell that started you, etc.)

Comment: What are you hoping to gain from having the stack near your code?  You were talking about EBP and ESP, not RBP and RBP, and in 32-bit x86 a `call rel32` or other relative references can reach any address from anywhere.  You either have +- 8-bit or +- 32-bit or 32-bit absolute, and an imm8 is not going to reach far enough.  Or are you talking about the stack of the emulated guest, and that somehow makes things better for your emulaotr?

Comment: Nothing stops you from allocating some memory for your own stack btw.

Comment: I'm doing jit, and for now I just translate emulated addresses to emulator addresses by doing a substraction, this makes me having a simple adddress translation process. And for now I want to keep it that way. Ideally I would like to have a non intrusive way of doing this stack modification. I'm thinking about parsing and modifying afterwards the output of the gdb tracing to change the addresses. Hard to explain sorry ... I may be better finding another way of testing my emulator.